# NodeJS HttpGet to a URL with JSON response

Tags: json, node.js, api, curl, httprequest

I'm trying to make a server-side API call using a RESTful protocol with a JSON response. I've read up on both the [API documentation](http://developer.cumtd.com/documentation/v2.2/Responses) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15558968/2865101).

The API that I'm trying to pull from tracks busses and returns data in a JSON output. I'm confused on how to make a HTTP GET request with all parameters and options in the actual URL.  The API and it's response can even be accessed through a browser or using the 'curl' command. http://developer.cumtd.com/api/v2.2/json/GetStop?key=d99803c970a04223998cabd90a741633&stop_id=it

How do I write Node server-side code to make GET requests to a resource with options in the URL and interpret the JSON response?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

#### `request` is now deprecated. It is recommended you use an alternative:

- native HTTP/S, `const https = require('https');`
- [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)
- [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)
- [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got)
- [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent)

[Stats comparision](https://www.npmtrends.com/axios-vs-node-fetch-vs-request-vs-superagent-vs-got)
[Some code examples](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html)

#### Original answer:

The request module makes this really easy. Install request into your package from npm, and then you can make a get request.

```
var request = require("request")

var url = "http://developer.cumtd.com/api/v2.2/json/GetStop?" +
    "key=d99803c970a04223998cabd90a741633" +
    "&stop_id=it"

request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body) // Print the json response
    }
})
```

You can find documentation for request on npm: https://npmjs.org/package/request

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @matt-esch! I read up on the examples on the 'request' npm page and they mention that the response stored by a way similar to "var resp = request(...)" but when I try to parse the result using "var parsed = JSON.parse(resp)" I get an error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o". I've tried searching for an answer but nothing really seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: In my example, setting `json` to `true` returns the parsed JSON as the body. The examples show that the return value of resp is a stream, not a value you can parse. The result is returned asynchronously either way.

Comment: Just wondering, for the code you provided, how do i know what request is it? i.e. post, get, delete or put? I don't see the code specify it... Thanks